# Using R how do I replace the values (or the absence of value) in a column with the values in a vector?

Tags: r

I got this matrix:

```
data <- c(1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

matrixData <- matrix(data, nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)

diag(matrixData) <- 0 # zeros out the diag of the matrix
lilMatrix  = fractions(sweep(matrixData, 2, colSums(matrixData), FUN="/"))`
lilMatrix

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    0  NaN  2/7    0  4/5  1/2
 [2,] 3/13  NaN  1/7    1    0    0
 [3,] 2/13  NaN    0    0  1/5    0
 [4,]    0  NaN  1/7    0    0  1/6
 [5,] 8/13  NaN  3/7    0    0  1/3
 [6,]    0  NaN    0    0    0    0
```

I just want to replace the `NaNs` in column [,2] with this stuff:

```
articleVector = fractions(c(3/14,2/14, 5/14, 1/14, 2/14, 1/14))
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Does `lilMatrix[, 2] <- c(3/14,2/14, 5/14, 1/14, 2/14, 1/14)` do what you want?

Comment: Actually, I believe he wants: `lilMatrix[,2] <- fractions(c(3/14,2/14, 5/14, 1/14, 2/14, 1/14))` where `fractions` is from the `MASS` package.

Comment: I didn't realize it was that easy. Should I remove this question?